# Should you say "Refu'ah Shleima" or "Hatov Vehameitiv" first to someone who has laryngitis?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

Let's say that you have a fairly close friend who talks too much *lashon hara*. You try to warn your friend not to speak so much gossip, but, your friend doesn't listen. You're getting annoyed at all this chatter.

One day, you speak to your friend, and discover that s/he has laryngitis. You're thinking that's a good thing, because s/he can't speak lashon hara. But, at the same time, you also hope that s/he recovers from the laryngitis and s/he doesn't get sicker. What should you wish **first**?

*Hatov Vehamaitiv* because you as well as others can't hear lashon hara or
*Refu'ah Shleima* - a speedy recovery

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: How is this Purim Torah (as opposed to regular Torah)?

Answer (score 3):

When the person has no voice, you say refuah sh'leimah. But when his voice begins to return and he is able to complain enough that you hear it, you say Hatov V'hameitiv, because he is able to produce a better whine.

Comment: It's a cute answer, but, that doesn't seem to address the lashon hara problem.

Answer (score 1):

Refua Shlaima would be said as the person needs a Refua from saying Lashon Hara also. Hatov V'Hameitiv would not be said as one can still be liable for Lashon Hara by writing it or by signalling with the eye.

Comment: Very astute!!!!